# Импортированные стили в ReactJS

Tags: css, reactjs

Делаю приложение на `ReactJS`.

Есть два "модуля" - `Admin`, `Operator`.

У каждого модуля свои стили. Есть конечно общие стили. С этим проблем нет.
Но вот есть стили которые относятся к модулю. 
Я их импортирую в компоненте страницы модуля (к примеру `LoginPage`), к примеру так:

```
import '../../style/page/auth/style.css';
import '../../style/page/auth/media.css';
import '../../style/page/auth/custom.css';
```

Но вот проблема в том что все стили, со всех страниц и модулей вставляются в `head` страницы. И стили будут перебиваться.

Как это пофиксить? что бы в `head` вставлялись стили только для нужного модуля.

в `index.js` у меня есть роутер:

```
<Router>
    <Switch>
        <Route path="/admin" component={AdminModule}/>
        <Route path="/operator" component={OperatorModule}/>
        <Route component={NotFoundPage}/>
    </Switch>
</Router>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Никак. Вы правильно заметили что все стили при компиляции проекта созданного c помощью *create-react-app* объединяются и помещаются в `<head></head>`

Следуйте каким-то конвенциям при написании стилей, например [БЭМ](https://ru.bem.info/methodology/) чтобы избежать перезаписи стилей.

Альтернативным решением является создание собственной кофигурации на Webpack, но я бы не советовал такой подход, потому что в данном случае он является скорее "костылем" нежели решением. create-react-app + конвенция для стилей = Best Practice